# mysqlcheck does not accept password

Tags: mysql, unix

According to the mysqlcheck manual I can do the following:

`mysqlcheck datatabase_name --auto-repair -ao -u="user" -p="password"`

However it never accepts the password. It does not matter whether I use the shell or database login. When I leave the password, i can connect after it prompts me to put the password. I want to put it in a cron script so i need to be able to put the password inside the command.

Also am i right that this command will analyse, optimise and repair if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
mysqlcheck datatabase_name --auto-repair -ao --user=user --password=password
```

or `-uuser or -ppassword should also work.`

Unfortunately I can't really provide any further insight into your queries on how effective **mysqlcheck** actually will be in what you want it to do. I suspect it won't do the things that will really improve DB performance though like adding well placed indexes and optimizing queries to only link where necessary.

Comment: Yeah i know. The biggest reason I want to put it is because sometimes the session table gets corrupted. I'll try it out